# a simple process jbpm 5 using gateway

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

I'm novice in jbpm 5. I try to create a simpel process with  diverge and converge geteway. I use this tutorial: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbpm/345-jbpm-5-tutorial-first-example.html?start=1,
but when I try to execute my process I get this error:

```
[-1,-1]: Process 'Hello World' [com.sample.bpmn.hello]: Join node 'Gateway' [7] has no type.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:67)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.readKnowledgeBase(ProcessMain.java:31)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:20)
 the geteway 7 is he converge geteway
```

Answer (score 0):

Type should be AND, OR or XOR if I don't remember wrong. 
Check the examples here: https://github.com/Salaboy/jBPM5-Developer-Guide